# Custom background for an ActionBar Item

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to set a custom background/drwable for my action bar item. Ideally to have the "Save job" thing as a "white text over dark blue" button.

[image]

Any hint ?

Answer (score 1):

Basic editting of action bar items straight from: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

```
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/SAVE_JOB"                     //Save job button
      android:textColorolor="Your hex color"         //Whatever color you want
      android:background="@drawable/yourbackground"  //Whatever picture you want
      android:showAsAction="always" />
```

The `yourbackground` will be located in your drawable folder, and your hex color will be in the fashion `#FFFFFF`.

Comment: I tried this but looks like it's not working with a custom background for the ActionBar. But thanks, I should have mentioned I tried the method in the doc.

Comment: @French You could create your own Action Bar I guess. Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190078/how-to-create-android-actionbar-with-custom-view-and-tabs?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.custom_bar, null);

    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Set your custom actionbarview and do whatever you want in xml.