# How add custom view top of the android action bar

Tags: android

[image]How to add a custom view top the android navigation bar like above  image. when user click on the action bar need to push the main content down and add the custom layout top of the action bar.please how to accomplish this any one suggest a solution

Thanks 
Rahul

Comment: I think [this link][1] maybe help you. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190078/how-to-create-android-actionbar-with-custom-view-and-tabs

Comment: thanks jerikc but i want ad the view top of the action bar need to push main content down.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to use those views in the actual ActionBar like this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView. And then take all your layouts and put them inside a RelativeLayout and set their android:layout_below="" to a layout that corresponds to the ActionBar you want to use. So in a step by step way:

1. Create an action_bar.xml that has the items you want your actionbar to have (ImageViews or Buttons, w/e)
2. Include this layout in all the Layouts you will use (or in your main layout if you're using Fragments to display content).Like this:

   ```
   <include layout="@layout/action_bar"
       android:id="@+id/action_bar"
       android: ... />
   ```
3. Make your Layout position itself below this layout (Using a FrameLayout for example)

   ```
    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/content_frame"
       android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
   ```
4. Include the ActionViews (Spinner and tabs) in the ActionBar like it's taught in the link up there.

Comment: Thanks holandaGo actually already we  implemented the action bar with navigation drawer. i want to add the the custom view above the android Action bar.any solution for this.

Comment: If you just want to add an ActionView to the ActionBar, it's taught in the link in the answer. This solution up there is so you can have different layers of ActionBars that are entirely editable by you and easy to do so.